# How to set custom folder names for views stores and models on ExtJs 4 application?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I ask this because there is an existing application that I would like to enable for using Sencha CMD so first step is to instantiate it via:

```
Ext.Application
```

which presents the first problem:

folder structure is

```
someApp
--Views
--Model
--Store
--moreFolders
```

(should be model, store, view)

Rather than refactoring  hundreds of classes(huge app) I want to set the folders path if possible.

Can you think in any drawbacks? What would your approach be?

Any ideas are very well received.

Using ExtJs 4.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Use [Ext.Loader.paths.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-paths)

You can actually set these against your Ext.application when initializing, for example:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'MyApp',
  paths: {
      'MyCustom': 'wherever/custom',
  },
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('MyCustom.view.List'); // Goes to wherever/custom/view/List.js
  }
});
```