# Is there a way to minify an ExtJS application without Sencha CMD?

Tags: maven, extjs, extjs4, minify, extjs4.2

I have an existing ExtJS app developed using ExtJS 4.2.1. 
I am using Closure minifier through Maven plugin minify-maven-plugin. 
The generated minified JS files (without merge) works fine. 
However, generated merged minified file throws undefined errors because the definition comes later in the merged file. 
My question is, is there a way I can figure out the order I have to provide the plugin? (I don't want to use Sencha Cmd)

The app folder follows the structure

app/common, app/controller, app/model, app/proxy, app/store, app/utils, app/view

At the moment this is how I have defined the build process in Maven POM file

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-minify</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                        <!--  <skipMerge>true</skipMerge> -->
                        <webappSourceDir>${basedir}/src/main</webappSourceDir>
                        <jsSourceDir>js/app</jsSourceDir>
                        <jsTargetDir>js/app</jsTargetDir>
                        <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                        <closureLanguage>ECMASCRIPT5</closureLanguage>
                        <closureAngularPass>true</closureAngularPass>
                        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                        <webappTargetDir>${project.build.directory}</webappTargetDir>
                        <jsSourceIncludes>
                            <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                        </jsSourceIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont use Sencha Cmd? It does exactly what you want!

Maybe it helps if you know that you can use Sencha Cmd without the Sencha application structure. If you want only merge the files use the [concatenate](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html#sencha_compile_concatenate) cmd.

If you really dont want use Sencha Cmd, then you have to take care of all the extends, requires, mixins and so on... and I would not recommend this!

For example use Sencha Cmd with manual paths and exclude the extjs classes

```
sencha compile --classpath=myApp/src,extjs/src -debug=false exclude -all and include -namespace MyApp.* and concat bundle.js
```

the extjs/src path is the path where your extjs classes are

Comment: can you elaborate on "you can use Sencha Cmd without the Sencha application structure" ? I have an application that doesn't have the conventional structure. See my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439463/how-to-set-custom-folder-names-for-views-stores-and-models-on-extjs-4-applicatio thanks

Comment: @SimonHoss, I have hit configuration issues with Sencha cmd
(so decided not to go that route). Moreover, if I know the order in which the files need to be added, I can easily do this using Maven build. Looks like it is not that simple. But is there a way I can get the list of loading order?

Comment: If you can use a json structure then maybe [jsduck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck) is something for you. With jsduck you can export your classes in json. In this json you have all the informations you need. (mixins, requires, extend...) Example cmd: jsduck app --output docs --export=full

Comment: @SimonHoss, managed to compile to a single file using Sencha Cmd. Thanks for the example compilation code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is about the order of of files for minification, providing that information below:

We had a similar requirement, where I could not use Sencha cmd as it is to minify files, so created jsb file on my own [I know this is not recommended :( ].

What I did was, created below jsb file **[please note:  sequence of files is very important]**:

```
{
"projectName": "ProductName",
"builds": [
/** This file is for production purpose **/
    {
        "name": "ProductName - Production",
        "target": "all-app.js",
        "compress": true,
        "files": [
        /** utils **/

            {
                "path": "app/util/",
                "name": "util.js"
            }
        /** models **/
            {
                "path": "app/model/",
                "name": "MyModel.js"
            },
        /** stores **/
            {
                "path": "app/store/",
                "name": "MyStore.js"
            },

        /** custom components  **/

            {
                "path": "resources/ux/form/",
                "name": "MySearchField.js"
            },
        /** views **/
            {
                "path": "app/view/admin/",
                "name": "MyView.js"
            },
        /** controllers **/
         {
                "path": "app/controller/",
                "name": "Window.js"
         },
        /** app.js **/

         {
                "path": "",
                "name": "app.js"
         }
        ]
    },
    /** This file is for debug purpose **/
    {
        "name": "ProductName - debug",
        "target": "all-app-debug.js",
        "compress": false,
        "files": [
        /** utils **/

            {
                "path": "app/util/",
                "name": "util.js"
            }
        /** models **/
            {
                "path": "app/model/",
                "name": "MyModel.js"
            },
        /** stores **/
            {
                "path": "app/store/",
                "name": "MyStore.js"
            },

        /** custom components  **/

            {
                "path": "resources/ux/form/",
                "name": "MySearchField.js"
            },
        /** views **/
            {
                "path": "app/view/admin/",
                "name": "MyView.js"
            },
        /** controllers **/
         {
                "path": "app/controller/",
                "name": "Window.js"
         },
        /** app.js **/

         {
                "path": "",
                "name": "app.js"
         }
        ]
    }
],
"resources" : []
```

}

If you create a minified file using above sequence, it will work in your case as well.

Hope this help. 
Thanks!

Comment: Pankaj, So, I have to compile the files in the directory according to what you mentioned above right? (Util, model, store, custom, view, controller and finally app.js)

Comment: Yes, you will have to compile the files in the directory as per above sequence.