# How can I minify an ExtJs 5 project without Sencha?

Tags: javascript, maven, extjs, minify

I have been researching the ability to minify an ExtJS application without Sencha and the closest I have come to is this link:

[Is there a way to minify an ExtJS application without Sencha CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565047/is-there-a-way-to-minify-an-extjs-application-without-sencha-cmd/29627026#29627026)

However, I am not sure how to execute the file in one of the later comments. I am using the minify-maven-plugin with com.samaxes.maven and the CLOSURE engine. I was able to generate the minified js file of the entire project but I get errors when I try to load the web page.

I was able to verify the web page was calling the correct file. I received the error "TypeError: q is undefined"...not helpful at all. Without the minified file, the web application runs perfectly. So, the generated minified file must have something wrong with it.

The suggestion at the bottom of the link above indicates the sequence of files that I should include but I have no idea how to actually implement this. Also, there are probably over a hundred javascript files that need to be minified so I would rather not have to type each file in the jsb file.

Are there any suggestions on how to minify my entire project at build time with maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to build the project, but it doesn't really matter as all you need is to combine files, so maven should be more than capable.

I wanted my dev version to still rely on Extjs dynamic class loader so I don't have to rebuild the project whenever I modify one file, and only production version to be minified into a single file. There were a few pitfalls before I got it working, here is what I ended up with. Also this is for ExtJS6, but it probably still should be the same.

It is all controlled by backend variable `dev`, which when set to `false` will use minified sources.

index.html (I'm using some meta templating language as example)

```
<html>
<head>
    {{if dev}}
        <script src="/ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    {{else}}
        <script src="/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    {{/if}}

    <script>
        var dev = {{dev}};
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: dev});
    </script>

    {{if dev}}
        <script src="/app.min.js"></script>
    {{else}}
        <script src="/app.js"></script>
    {{/if}}
</head>
<body></body>
<html>
```

app files, `requires` directive doesn't work well when the dynamic loader is disabled, so I had to add conditions like this everywhere:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Panel', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.GenericPanel',
    requires: dev ? [
       'MyApp.view.AnotherView',
    ] : [],
    ...
});
```

Gruntfile.js (if you need only concatenation replace `uglify` with `concat` everywhere)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg : grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify : {
            build: {
                files: {
                    '../app.min.js': ['../app/view/GenericPanel.js', '../app/**/*.js', '../app.js'],
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'uglify' ]);
};
```

grunt's project.json:

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

The order of files matter, by default grunt will use alphabetic order. If you extend some class, the parent class has to be included higher. `app.js` should be at the end. Other than that it is working well in a single mixed file, so I didn't have to customize the file order further. Grunt has pretty powerful [path patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), so if you need to make sure some file is included first you just list it before other path patterns and it will be smart enough to not include it twice.

I recommend you start with simple concatenation without minification, and only if that works try minifying it. When minifying you might need to be careful with global functions and variables as they can be renamed if minifier is too aggressive. Grunt's minifier almost worked for me with the default settings, I just had to made couple small changes to my code (related to global functions).

Comment: +1 @serg.
This is great information! I was looking through the maven documentation and realized what was wrong. The minifier was only trying to minify a specific folder, rather than the folder that needed to be minified. I needed to change the source folder that I wanted to minify. I also did need to ensure I was minifying the folders in the correct order, with app.js at the end just like you said. I also added the conditionals to the requires statements, that was a huge help! This enabled me to set up a configuration file to either use the minified app or the normal app for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure why you would want this, the main thing you need is the so-called dependency tree - which tells you the order in which to include the source files.

Then you can put all the files (ExtJS source, libraries if applicable and also your own views) into one big file, in the correct order. This file should then work exactly as the 500 distinct files. (It did for me.)

That done, you can search for a working minifier. Not every minifier can minify ExtJS code, and I don't remember my last results before we finally decided to switch to Sencha Cmd, but I think Microsoft Javascript Minifier was one that worked for us.

Apart from that, minified JavaScript is really legible. You should provide the source of the error, with 200 characters before and 200 characters after the error, and I guess someone here can tell what's going on there.

Comment: I want to minify the files because ExtJS is slow and needs to be optimized. I wanted to stay away from manually typing all of the files, but it seems I cannot do that, as I always get a lot of errors. I am currently using the minifier for my css files, which works great. All of the files that I use with ExtJS are *.js files so I am actually going through the entire project and trying to figure out the correct order to load the files. And then modifying the pom.xml file to have the correct order.
Thanks for the response, I really appreciate it. I'm getting close to finishing this arduous task!